# Rules of the Annual Purge?

Tags: the-purge

Is it legal to kill or harm children in the purge? It says that ONLY LEVEL 10 government officials are immune... but I dont know if there are more rules about children stated in the movies and shows.

Comment: Rules would kind of defeat the purpose, no?

Comment: Rule #1 is that there are no rules

Comment: *Purge ‘em all !!!* -NFFA

Comment: Can you tell us what makes you suspect there may have been rules about that? I don't think the question requires it, but it may make the question easier to address.

Answer (score 7):

It says it right at the start of the first film; "[Any and all crime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbUTbqwKtEE&feature=youtu.be&t=129)".

I think we can reasonably assume that includes murdering a child, unless said child happens to be a Government official of rank 10.

[image]

Purely for the record, in the first film, the antagonist tries to kill the protagonist's children. No attempt is made to dissuade him by reading him the rules.

Comment: thats ouns movie based true, My question is more about how stupid that idea and position is, simply because it's so easy to follow through with... I wonder if there are rules beyond that.

Comment: @TheIcePhoenix Well... No, there aren't. No?